# Building a HashMap where the key is a field in the structure and the value is the structure itself

Tags: rust

I want to build a `HashMap` of a vector of structures where the key is a `String` field in the structure and the value is the structure itself. It seems like this should be possible without copying. I want to move the lifetime of the structure to the `HashMap` and then the key would have the same lifetime since it's valid as long as the `HashMap` contains the structure.

```
use std::collections::{HashMap};

#[derive(Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct A {
    pub x: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(A { x: "foo".to_string() });
    for x in vec {
        map.insert(&x.x, x);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
src/main.rs:13:19: 13:22 error: `x.x` does not live long enough
src/main.rs:13       map.insert(&x.x, x);
                                 ^~~
src/main.rs:9:34: 15:2 note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 9:33...
src/main.rs: 9     let mut map = HashMap::new();
src/main.rs:10     let mut vec = Vec::new();
src/main.rs:11     vec.push(A { x: "foo".to_string() });
src/main.rs:12     for x in vec {
src/main.rs:13       map.insert(&x.x, x);
src/main.rs:14     }
               ...
src/main.rs:12:5: 14:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the for at 12:4
src/main.rs:12     for x in vec {
src/main.rs:13       map.insert(&x.x, x);
src/main.rs:14     }
```

Any help sorting this out is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot do this. For one, you are trying to take a reference to a value where the address is only valid for the one statement before it's moved. You also [can't store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423), so the end goal is unreachable. Also, note that the [vector has nothing to do with your question](http://is.gd/vh6kD6).

Comment: *the key would have the same lifetime since it's valid as long as the HashMap contains the structure* — not true;  as soon as the `HashMap` decides to reallocate the storage of the values, any references would be invalidated.

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, it is true that the key will not be dropped until the value is removed from the HashMap. That was the point I was trying to make. I see the point you're making in your earlier comment though. Thanks!